# How to fix the spacing between my input and button?

Tags: html, css

I have an input tag for a search bar and a button to the right where users can click to hit enter. However, there's a spacing between the search box and the button and I'm not able to find out why. I tried using chrome's inspect element to find out if the reason if because of some misplaced padding-left/right but nothing indicates that, so I'm not sure why.
Here's my html and css

```css
.left-nav input[type=text] {
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.left-nav ::placeholder {
  padding-left: 6px;
}

.left-nav button {
  padding: 11px 15px;
  background: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="left-nav">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg" ></i></button>
</div>
```

[How it's currently showing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2eKls.jpg)

Comment: can you please create a [codepen](https://codepen.io/pen/)?

Comment: Did you try reducing the margin for the button ?

Comment: The margin calls are all for left aspect, which positions my button where I want it on my webpage, so this shouldn't affect the right aspect of the button itself. However, I did try reducing the values and this didn't work

Comment: You could move the margin attributes to the root element which is the `div.left-nav` and then have another margin set for the button inside the parent div. Your outer div margin would handle the webpage alignment and this would help with the button alignment inside the div.

Comment: Adding a `margin-left: -4px;` to `.left-nav button` in your snippet removed the extra space.

Comment: I was thinking of doing the -px but I was unsure whether this was good practice?

Answer (score 2):

Place your `input` and `button` in **one** line. Then, the spacing shall be removed.

```css
body {
  background-color: darkSlateGray;
}

.left-nav input[type=text] {
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.left-nav ::placeholder {
  padding-left: 6px;
}

.left-nav button {
  padding: 11px 15px;
  background: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>

<div class="left-nav">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."><button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg" ></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked! Why did it leave a space just because the tags where in separate lines?

Comment: a line break between the element count as a space

Comment: @yinsweet This is interesting!

Comment: @yinsweet I don't agree with that fact of a line break. It is because of inline elements. as Gerald  has answered the ques.

Comment: @SandeshSapkota You are right. It is because of the line break between the **inline elements** causing a space.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is related to the [space between inline-block elements](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/). There are several ways to fix this of which I would recommend making `.left-nav` a [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

```css
.left-nav {
  display: flex;
}

.left-nav input[type=text] {
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.left-nav::placeholder {
  padding-left: 6px;
}

.left-nav button {
  padding: 11px 15px;
  background: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.13.0/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="left-nav">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg" ></i></button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a margin to your button like below:

```
.left-nav button {
  padding: 11px 15px;
  background: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: -4px;
}
```

You can adjust the margin based on what you see on your screen (as this value is what did the work in your snippet.)

Comment: That's not the question. The question is why it's happening at the first place.

Comment: The issue is due to inline-blocks giving extra spacing between two items.

Answer (score 0):

The line feed between the  and  creates a space between them on the page. You have to remove the line feed, or use this trick this will remove the space without having margin-left as negative.

```css
.left-nav input[type=text] {
  background-color: #2B2B2B;
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding: 8px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 8px 0px 0px 8px;
  font-size: 17px;
  display: inline;
}

.left-nav ::placeholder {
  padding-left: 6px;
}

.left-nav button {
  display: inline;
  padding: 11px 15px;
  background: rgb(184, 184, 184);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 0px 8px 8px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
<div class="left-nav">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  <button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg" ></i></button>
</div>
<br>

<!--the Problem is the line feed you can remove it or add this comment btw them-->
<div class="left-nav">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search..."><!--
    --><button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search fa-lg" ></i></button>
</div>

<!--Hope this helps-->
```